# How to config wget to retry more than 20?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, wget

I used d4x to continue download, but it's obsolete from ubuntu. So I use flashgot with wget to continue download. But wget stops after 20 tries, I have to restart manually. Is there any conf file I could modify the retry times more than 20?

The wget CLI is automatic created by wget, so please don't tell me I could make options with the wget CLI.

Comment: Write a loop in bash?

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Startup-File for info on using the .wgetrc startup file.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Use [the `--tries` option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget):

```
wget --tries=42 http://example.org/
```

Specify `--tries=0` or `--tries=inf` for infinite retrying (default is 20 retries).

The default value also can be changed via config file, if that is your thing; open `/etc/wgetrc` and look there for:

```
# You can lower (or raise) the default number of retries when
# downloading a file (default is 20).
#tries = 20
```

uncomment `tries=20` and change it to what you want.

> The default is to retry 20 times, with the exception of fatal errors
>   like "connection refused" or "not found" (404), which are not retried

Comment: Upvoted,but,please also mention that `The default is to retry 20 times, with the exception of
           fatal errors like "connection refused" or "not found" (404), which
           are not retried.
`

Answer (score 7):

If the default retry value can not meet your needs, it seems you are downloading from an unstable source.

The following option may also help a lot.

```
--retry-connrefused  --read-timeout=20 --timeout=15 --tries=0 --continue
```

`--retry-connrefused`
Force wget to retry even the server refuses requests, otherwise wget will stop to retry.

`--waitretry=1`
If you decide to retry many times, it's better to add some short period between each retry.

`--timeout=15`
unstable link always cause stopping of data flow, the default 900s timeout is too long. There is `--dns-timeout`, `--connect-timeout`, and `--read-timeout`. By specify `--timeout`, you update them all at the same time.

`--tries=0`
Make wget to retry infinity except fatal situations such as 404.

`--continue`
resume download

2023-02-28T17:59:32 added

Recently, I found wget will auto exist after severl tries on a very unstable link, with all the options above configured.

So, I come up with a autohotkey script, which will check if wget is still running. If not, it will bring up it again.

```
; AutoHotkey Version: 1.x
; Language:       English
; Platform:       WinXP/7
; Author:         studotwho
; Url:        https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/66615-continuously-check-if-a-program-is-running-and-start-it/
;
; Script Function:
;   Restarts the iTeleportConnect service if it hasn't started - this usually happens if your
;   wireless network interface hasn't started when iTC tries to connect.
;
;   This script loops every (45) seconds to determine if iTC is running or not, and restarts it if it's not.
;

#SingleInstance, force
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

iTC_EXE     = C:\usrprogs\wget-1.19.4-win32\lowspeeddown.bat
iTC_Path    = C:\usrprogs\wget-1.19.4-win32
iTC_imgName = wget.exe

loop {
    sleep 3000
    Process, Exist, %iTC_imgName% ; check to see if iTeleportConnect is running
    If (ErrorLevel = 0) ; If it is not running
       {
       Run, %iTC_EXE%, %iTC_Path%
       }
    Else ; If it is running, ErrorLevel equals the process id for the target program (Printkey). Then do nothing.
       {
        sleep 5
       }
}
```

2024-02-16T18:47:08

Sorry, I just noticed that the question is about running wget binary by flashgot on a ubuntu system.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).